# canvas HTML + OOP with Javascript - multiple objects and 'dependency'

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

I'm currently learning object oriented programming with Javascript and i recently tried canvas as a field for learning and experimenting things in OOP. Canvas is also a powerful tool. This JSFiddle sheet above is also an opportunity for me to go ahead maths and physics, trying to understand things before coding.

What i'm trying to achieve here is a very simple solar system that i draw on paper before, using class and prototype with HTML canvas. It's working for now but i want to improve it to go ahead OOP. I also fell some limitations without using objects. Things seems to be less 'natural' without it. [Here is a link to a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itachi_uchiha/g9r3sy0x/)
. As you can see, i created instances of my main class Circle but i'm not really fully using the true potential of objects and their attributes.
In HTML canvas, an element after another will in a certain way 'inherite' properties from the previous one like the moon satellite rotating around a earth. I applied a translation on the moon and its initial position is based on the previous translation applied to the earth. As this, the moon will always 'follow' the earth :

```
// CIRCLE 01 as a earth
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 60) * t.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 60000) * t.getMilliseconds());
ctx.translate(130, 0);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0, 0, circle01.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.fill();

// LINE between earth and moon
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = colorGreen;
ctx.moveTo(circle00.x, circle00.y);
ctx.lineTo(circle02.x + 30, circle02.y);
ctx.stroke();
// orbite circle 01
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = colorRed;
ctx.arc(0, 0, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.stroke();

// CIRCLE 02 as a moon
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 6) * t.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 6000) * t.getMilliseconds());
ctx.translate(30, 0);
ctx.arc(0, 0, circle02.radius, 0, Math.PI * 1, false);
ctx.fill();
// simulate the darkside of the moon
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.stroke();
```

It working but it seems 'not natural' to do it like that and what i really want to do is saying something like the central axis of rotation for the moon will be the x and y positions of the earth (it's what i called dependency in the main title of the question. The moon will let say depend of earth).

Same for the green line between them. I want this line always pointing from center axis of earth to center axis of the moon, moving with both, as i tried to wrote it :

```
ctx.moveTo(circle00.x, circle00.y);
ctx.lineTo(circle02.x + 30, circle02.y);
```

/////

About the prototype speed, i think that i have to wrote it with a circular motion equation including distance and time. I find links to wikipedia pages about that but for now i'm not able to implement it, due to my light knowledge on math and physics, it tacks me time to understand it before trying to implementing it.
For now, i'm using this piece of code that i read on a MDN tutorial about animation and canvas :

```
ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 60) * t.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 60000) * t.getMilliseconds());
```

I don't really understand the effect of the time on such animation.
At the beginning, i used a rotation based on an incrementation of the angle :

```
var angle = 0;
ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * (angle));
angle += Math.PI / 64;
```

Otherwise i tried rotation it in another sheet, using DOM, Math.cos and Math.sin methods like this :

```
formC.style.left = 300 + 20 * Math.cos(angle) + 'px';
formC.style.top = 250 + 20 * Math.sin(angle) + 'px';
angle += 0.05;
```

////////

What i want to achieve is create independent objects that can communicate each other plus share their properties, and implement a solid method for manage the speed of the objects. Also want to have a better understanding of trigonometry and Pythagoras theorem, and motion.

Can you show me a better way to achieve it using object oriented programming and explain what is the effects of getSeconds() and getMilliseconds() methods on the animation?